# Values from the database is not being displayed in Dynamic report

Tags: java, hql, dynamic-reports

The requirement is to fetch data from the databse and display it in dynamic report,but when i try to pass a list through createDataSource() and make a call to report.setDataSource(createDataSource()),it still display's empty value in the report,am able to display the column headers like jobid,status_value and mobile_no,but their corresponding value is empty even if the value exists in database,pls help!am i in the right path

> java code

package com.unify.avcv.utils.threads;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.hyphenation.TernaryTree.Iterator;
import com.unify.avcv.hibernate.util.HibernateDBUtil;
import com.unify.avcv.hibernate.model.AvcvJobData;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.*;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.column.Columns;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.column.TextColumnBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component.TextFieldBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.style.StyleBuilder;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant.HorizontalAlignment;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception.DRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.dynamicreports.report.datasource.DRDataSource;


import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.w3c.dom.*;


import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;


public class DynamicReportsGeneration {




    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DRException {
        try
        {
        JasperReportBuilder report=DynamicReports.report();
        StyleBuilder boldstyle=DynamicReports.stl.style().bold();
        StyleBuilder boldstyle_center=DynamicReports.stl.style(boldstyle).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        TextFieldBuilder<String> Title=DynamicReports.cmp.text("My First Dynamic Report");
        Title.setStyle(boldstyle_center);
        report.title(Title);

        TextColumnBuilder<String> job_id=Columns.column("jobid", "jobId", DynamicReports.type.stringType());
        TextColumnBuilder<Integer> status_value=Columns.column("status_value", "status", DynamicReports.type.integerType());
        TextColumnBuilder<BigInteger> mobile_value=Columns.column("mobile_no", "mobileNo", DynamicReports.type.bigIntegerType());

        report.columns(job_id,status_value,mobile_value);
        report.setDataSource(createDataSource());
        report.show();
        System.out.println("done!");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static JRDataSource createDataSource() {

        DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("jobid", "status_value", "mobile_no");
        Session session = (Session) HibernateDBUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        String avcvAuditLogQuery = "select jobId,status,mobileNo from AvcvJobData where mobileNo="+8888888811L;
        List<AvcvJobData> avcvAuditLogResult = session.createQuery(avcvAuditLogQuery).list();
        dataSource.add(avcvAuditLogQuery);
        return dataSource;

        }



}
```

AvcvJobData.java(POJO file)

```
package com.unify.avcv.hibernate.model;

import java.util.Date;

public class AvcvJobData implements java.io.Serializable, Cloneable {

    private String jobId;
    private Integer status;
    private long mobileNo;


    public AvcvJobData() {
    }

    public AvcvJobData(String jobId, long mobileNo) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    public AvcvJobData(String jobId, Integer status, long mobileNo
            ) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.status = status;
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;

    }

    public String getJobId() {
        return this.jobId;
    }

    public void setJobId(String jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public long getMobileNo() {
        return this.mobileNo;
    }

    public void setMobileNo(long mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

}
```

> AvcvJobData.hbm.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.unify.avcv.hibernate.model.AvcvJobData" table="avcv_job_data" catalog="avcvmts">
            <id name="jobId" type="string">
                <column name="job_id" length="15" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
            <property name="status" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="status" />
            </property>
            <property name="mobileNo" type="long">
                <column name="mobile_no" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="cafNo" type="string">
                <column name="caf_no" length="20" />
            </property>

        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should take a look at :

```
TextColumnBuilder<BigInteger> mobile_value=Columns.column("mobile_no", "mobileNo", DynamicReports.type.bigIntegerType());
```

You declare `mobile_value` column that does not exist and `job_id`  that is not a report column name.

```
    report.columns(job_id,status_value,mobile_value);
```

Try this:

```
    report.columns(jobId,status_value,mobile_no);
```